# What's the easiest way to draw significance lines and asteriks in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

So I have a good plot created in R consisting of 12 box plots. However, I need to do t-tests between them pair by pair and show their significance using the conventional bracketed lines and asterisks symbol. Is there no automated way to achieve this rather than using geom_line() manually to make every single line?

An example plot is shown below for what I would like to recreate except I'd like to do it for 12 plots instead of just 2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your data, but you may try using `ggsignif` package.

For an example data `df`,

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggsignif)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)


df <- data.frame(
  young = c(2:9),
  old = seq(1, by = .5, length.out = 8)
)
df %>%
  melt %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("young", "old")),
              method = "t.test",
              map_signif_level = TRUE)
```

[image]